# Find asymptotics of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n/3} 2^i \binom{n-i-1}{\frac{2n}{3}-1}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation, series-expansion

I have an expression

```
2^n / Sum[ 2^i Binomial[ n - i - 1, 2n/3 - 1], { i, 0, n/3}]
```

> ```
> 2^n / ( Binomial[ -1 + n, -1 + (2 n)/3] Hypergeometric2F1[ 1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2])
> ```

I would like to find if there is an exact asymptotic expression for this for large $n$.
I suspect it is something like $\;\sqrt{n}\;\;1.06^{\;n}\quad$ from numerical experiments.
Is it possible to work out it out exactly using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try plotting DiscretePlot[1/n Log[1/Sqrt[n]2^n/Sum[2^i*Binomial[n-i-1,2*n/3-1],{i,0,n/3}],{n,1,100,3}] and see if it converges to Log[1.06].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way without hypergeometric functions.

Binomial asymptotics is

```
bin = Normal@Series[Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {n, ∞, 0}, {i, ∞, 0}] // FullSimplify
```

> $\displaystyle\frac{2^{-2 n/3} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} 3^{n-i}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$

Approximately sum is integral

```
sum = Integrate[bin, {i, 0, n/3}]
```

> $\displaystyle\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2 n/3} \left(3^{n/3}-1\right)
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{\pi } \ln 3}$

Its asymptotics is $\;\frac{3^n\;2^{-\frac{2n}{3}}}{\sqrt{n}}$.

As a result we have

$$
\frac{2^n \sqrt{n}}{3^n2^{-\frac{2n}{3}}} = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2^{5/3}}{3}\right)^n \approx \sqrt{n}\;1.06^{\;n}
$$

---

**Analysis of hypergeometric functions**

From Hector answer:

```
Series[2^n/Sum[2^i*Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {i, 0, 
      n/3}], {n, ∞, 1}] // FullSimplify // Normal
```

[image]

At the first glance `Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2]` is a nightmare. However, let us analyze its asyptotics. By definition `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z]` is

```
Sum[(Gamma[a + k] Gamma[b + k] Gamma[c])/(Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[c + k]) z^k/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z]
> ```

In our case

```
a = 1;
b = -n/3;
c = 1 - n;
z = 2;
```

Let us consider one term of the sum above. We are interested in the case when $\ n\!\!\mod 3 = 0$. `Gamma` is undefined for negative integers but we can take a limit

```
g = FullSimplify[
  Limit[(Gamma[a + k] Gamma[b + k] Gamma[c])/(
    Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[c + k]) z^k/k!, n -> 3 m, 
   Assumptions -> {m \[Element] Integers, k \[Element] Integers, 
     m > k > 0}], Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Integers}]
```

[image]

Now we can consider the series about $m = \infty$

```
s = Normal@Series[g, {m, ∞, 0}]
```

> ```
> (3/2)^-k
> ```

It doesn't depend on `m`!

Therefore, `Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2]` is equal to 3 for big $n$!

```
Sum[s, {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> 3

Numerical verification:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
NLimit[Hypergeometric2F1[1, -Round[n, 3]/3, 1 - Round[n, 3], 2], n -> ∞]
```

> 2.99998

As a result the asymptotics is

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{3} \left(\frac{2^{5/3}}{3}\right)^n
$$

Comment: I made a comment (and then erased it) about `Hypergeometric2F1` having a singularity. I deleted my comment because that is just part of the story.

Comment: Thank you! Why are the two asymptotic results slightly different out of interest?

Comment: @felix The first approach is simple but rough and didn't give the correct coefficient.

Comment: Using `Pochhammer` instead of `Gamma` in the definition of `g` simplifies the derivation.

Answer (score 5):

I find it very interesting that Mathematica does not simplify the numerator:

```
Series[2^n/Sum[2^i*Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {i, 0, n/3}], {n, ∞, 1}]
     // FullSimplify // Normal
```

[image]

Using the obvious simplification, we get:

```
behavior = (2^(5 n/3) 3^-n Sqrt[n] Sqrt[π]) / Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2]
exact = Table[ Log@N@(2^n/Sum[2^i*Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {i, 0, n/3}]), {n, 300, 1000, 3}];
approx = Table[Log@N@behavior, {n, 300, 1000, 3}];
estim = Table[Log@N@(Sqrt[n] 1.06^n), {n, 300, 1000, 3}];
ListPlot[{exact, approx, estim}, PlotLegends -> {"exact", "approx", "estim"}]
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

I would use `Series[blah,{n,∞,1}]`:

```
behavior = Series[Sum[2^i*Binomial[n-i-1, 2*n/3-1], {i, 0, n/3}], {n, ∞, 1}]
     //FullSimplify//Normal
```

[image]

Your estimation however seems to be off:

```
exact = Table[Log@N@Sum[2^i*Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {i, 0, n/3}], {n,300, 1000, 3}];
approx = Table[Log@N@behavior, {n, 300, 1000, 3}];
estim = Table[Log@N@(Sqrt[n] 1.06^n), {n, 300, 1000, 3}];
ListPlot[{exact, approx, estim}, PlotLegends -> {"exact", "approx", "estim"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There was a typo I just fixed in the question.

Comment: `Hypergeometric2F1[1, -n/3, 1 - n, 2]` is equal to 3 for big n. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: Use `// Normal // FullSimplify` instead of `// FullSimplify // Normal` to achieve the desired simplification.

Answer (score 2):

In the process of addressing question [85900](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85900/asymptotics-of-frac-sum-i-0-lfloor-n-2-rfloor-2n-2i-choose-n-2i/85947#85947), I noticed that the question above can be solved compactly as follows.  The solution draws upon insights from the answers by Hector and ybeltukov.

```
Series[2^n/Sum[2^i*Binomial[n - i - 1, 2*n/3 - 1], {i, 0, n/3}], {n, ∞, 0}] 
    // Normal // FullSimplify[#, n > 0] &
(* 2^(5 n/3) 3^-n Sqrt[n π]/Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2] *)

Series[Pochhammer[1, k] Pochhammer[-n/3, k]/Pochhammer[1 - n, k] /. 
    n -> 3 m, {m, ∞, 1}] // Normal // FullSimplify[#, k ∈ Integers] &
(* 3^-k Pochhammer[1, k] *)

%% /. Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(n/3), 1 - n, 2] -> Sum[% 2^k/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]
(* 2^(5 n/3) 3^(-1 - n) Sqrt[n π] *)
```

Comment: That's very nice!