# Asymptotics of sum of binomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I would like to find the asymptotics of

```
Sum[Binomial[n,i]*1/i^((n+1)/2),{i,1,n}]
```

I saw [Find asymptotics of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n/3} 2^i \binom{n-i-1}{\frac{2n}{3}-1}$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32950/find-asymptotics-of-sum2ibinomialn-i-1-2n-3-1-i-0-n-3) but I can't get anything similar to work in my example.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: `f[n_] := Sum[Binomial[n, i]/i^((n + 1)/2), {i, 1, n}]; a = 
 Table[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]`

Comment: @belisarius This seems to imply the asymptotic is exactly $n$.

Comment: Now prove it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by looking at this graph

```
DiscretePlot[
 Sum[Binomial[n, i]/i^((n + 1)/2), {i, 1, n}]/n, {n, 500, 550}]
```

[image]

So we have the hypothesis that the sum increases like $n$. Let's use Mathematica to prove that the sum $S$ divided by $n$ goes to 1.

We have

```
Limit[1/n Binomial[n, i]/i^n, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> i >= 2]
```

> 0

So all but the first term go to 0. But we have a lot of such terms, so this is not enough to say the "rest of the sum" $R$ goes to 0. We prove that the sum from `i=3` onwards goes to 0.

We have

```
Limit[n Binomial[n, n/2]/3^n, n -> Infinity]
```

> 0

This proves that the sum from i=3 onwards goes to 0, as the Binomial coefficient is maximal when `i=n/2`, `1/(i^n)` is maximal when `i=3` and we have `n-2` ~ `n` terms.

The second term also goes to 0, so indeed the "rest of the sum", i.e. $R$, goes to 0.

The first term is

```
n == Binomial[n,1]*1^x
```

So we have that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S}{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n} + \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{R}{n} = 1+0 = 1$$