# Asymptotics of $\frac{\sum _{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {2(n-2i) \choose n-2i} {n \choose 2i} {4i \choose 2i}}{2^{3n - 1}}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation

I am fairly sure that asymptotically $$\frac{\sum _{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {2(n-2i) \choose n-2i} {n \choose 2i} {4i \choose 2i}}{2^{3n - 1}} \sim \frac{2}{\pi n}.$$

I tried

> Limit[n*Sum[Binomial[2n-4i,n-2i]*Binomial[n,2i]*Binomial[4i,2i],{i,0,n/2}]/2^(3n-1), n-> Infinity]

but Mathematica can't compute it.

Is there another way to persuade Mathematica to do this sort of asymptotics?

In [Find asymptotics of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n/3} 2^i \binom{n-i-1}{\frac{2n}{3}-1}$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32950/find-asymptotics-of-sum2ibinomialn-i-1-2n-3-1-i-0-n-3?rq=1) there is a clever use of Normal@Series as well as some other ideas for getting asymptotics but I didn't manage to get them to work for this problem.

Comment: tt = Sum[Binomial[2 n - 4 i, n - 2 i]*Binomial[n, 2 i]*
     Binomial[4 i, 2 i], {i, 0, n/2}]/2^(3 n - 1);
tt2 = tt/(2/Pi/n);
Table[tt2, {n, {25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 1000, 10000}}] // N returns {1.00092,1.00021,1.00005,1.00002,1.00001,1.00001,1.,1.}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `n` even, the `Sum` in the question can be performed explicitly,

```
Evaluate[Unevaluated[n*Sum[Binomial[2 n - 4 i, n - 2 i]*Binomial[n, 2 i]*
         Binomial[4 i, 2 i], {i, 0, Floor[n/2]}]/2^(3 n - 1)] /. 
         n -> 2 m /. Floor[(2*m)/2] -> m] // Simplify
(* 4^(1 - 3 m) m Binomial[4 m, 2 m] HypergeometricPFQ[
         {1/4, 3/4, 1/2 - m, 1/2 - m, -m, -m}, {1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/4 - m, 3/4 - m}, 1] *)
```

and then partially expanded

```
f65 = Simplify[Series[%, {m, Infinity, 0}] // Normal, m > 0 && m ∈ Integers]
(* (2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 3/4, 1/2 - m, 1/2 - m, -m, -m}, 
         {1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/4 - m, 3/4 - m}, 1])/Sqrt[π] *}
```

(A similar calculation can, of course, be obtained for `n` odd.)  Next, `f65` is represented as a [series of `Pochhammer` symbols](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

```
2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m/π] Sum[
  Pochhammer[1/4, k] Pochhammer[3/4, k] Pochhammer[-m, k]^2 Pochhammer[1/2 - m, k]^2/
  (Pochhammer[1/2, k]^2 Pochhammer[1, k] Pochhammer[1/4 - m, k] Pochhammer[3/4 - m, k])/k!
  , {k, 0, ∞}]
```

Large `m` expansions of the sort described in [32950](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32950/find-asymptotics-of-sum2ibinomialn-i-1-2n-3-1-i-0-n-3?rq=1) only work for ratios of equal numbers of `Pochhammer` symbols involving `m`.  So, expand just the ratio of the last two `Pochhammer` symbols in the numerator and denominator.

```
Series[Pochhammer[1/2 - m, k]^2/(Pochhammer[1/4 - m, k] Pochhammer[3/4 - m, k]), {m, ∞, 1}]
   // Normal // FullSimplify[#, k ∈ Integers] &
(* (E^((1/96)/m) (-1 + 96 m))/(96 m) *)
Limit[%, m -> ∞]
(* 1 *)
```

Hence, in this limit `f65` reduces to

```
f43 = 2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m/π] Sum[
  Pochhammer[1/4, k] Pochhammer[3/4, k] Pochhammer[-m, k]^2/
  (Pochhammer[1/2, k]^2 Pochhammer[1, k])/k!
  , {k, 0, ∞}]
(* (2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m/π] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 3/4, -m, -m}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}, 1] *)
```

At this point it is, perhaps, worth noting that

```
f43 /. m -> 100000 // N[#, 10] &
(* 0.6366197724 *)
```

still is equal to `2/π` to `10` significant figures.  Interestingly, the terms in the `f43` `Sum` can be further simplified by

```
t43s = FullSimplify[2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m/π] Pochhammer[1/4, k] Pochhammer[3/4, k] 
          Pochhammer[-m, k]^2/(Pochhammer[1/2, k]^2 Pochhammer[1, k])/k!,
          k ∈ Integers && m ∈ Integers]
(* (2^(3/2 + 2 k - 2 m) Sqrt[m]
      Gamma[1/2 + 2 k] Pochhammer[-m, k]^2)/(π Gamma[1 + 2 k]^2) *)
```

but summing over `t43s` just returns `f43`.  I know of no exact simplifications of `f43` in the large `m` limit, although one may exist.

Because `Pochhammer[-m, k]` vanishes for `k > m` and `m` a positive integer, it is possible to evaluate and plot every non-vanishing `t43s`.  For instance,

```
ListPlot[Table[t43s /. m -> 1000, {k, 0, 1000}], DataRange -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

A quite good fit to this curve is given by

```
4/π^(3/2) m^(-1/2) Exp[-4 m ((k - m/2)/m)^2]`
```

The coefficient `4/π^(3/2) m^(-1/2)` can be obtained from

```
Assuming[m > 0 && m ∈ Integers, Series[(2^(3/2 + 2 k - 2 m) Sqrt[m] Gamma[1/2 + 2 k] 
  Pochhammer[-m, k]^2)/(π Gamma[1 + 2 k]^2) /. k -> m/2, {m, ∞, 0}]] // Normal
```

for even `m`.  An expansion of `t43s` about `k = m/2` then gives the width `2/Sqrt[m]`.  The resulting agreement is very good, as can be seen from

```
With[{m = 1000}, ListLogPlot[{Table[(2^(3/2 + 2 k - 2 m) Sqrt[m]
        Gamma[1/2 + 2 k] Pochhammer[-m, k]^2)/(π Gamma[1 + 2 k]^2), {k, 0, m}], 
        Table[(2 m)^-(1/2) Exp[-4 m ((k - m/2)/m)^2], {k, 0, m}]}, 
        DataRange -> 1, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

(`t43s` is blue, the fitted function orange.)  The fitted function can be integrated to give

```
Assuming[ m > 0, Integrate[4/π^(3/2) m^(-1/2) Exp[-4 m ((k - m/2)/m)^2], {k, -∞, ∞}]]
(* 2/π *)
```

as desired.

**Addendum: Improved Proof Based on Pochhammer Substitution**

The barrier to expanding `f43` is `Pochhammer[-m, k]`, which is not continuous for positive integer `m` and `k`.  However, even though Mathematica appears not to know it,

```
Assuming[m >= k >= 0 && (m | k) ∈ Integers, 
  Pochhammer[-m, k]^2 == Pochhammer[m + 1 - k, k]^2]
```

is `True`, as can be seen empirically by trying numerous values of `m` and `k`.  Furthermore, making this substitution into the expression above for `f43` gives the same result as before.  So, let us focus on the alternative representation,

```
t43a = (2^(3/2 - 2 m) Sqrt[m] Pochhammer[1/4, k] Pochhammer[3/4, k] 
  Pochhammer[m + 1 - k, k]^2)/(Sqrt[π] k! Pochhammer[1/2, k]^2 Pochhammer[1, k])
```

Because it is apparent from the first plot above that `t43a` is large only near `k = m/2`, `t43a` should be expanded for large `m` with `k = a m`.

```
(Assuming[0 < a < 1, Series[t43a /. k -> a m, {m, ∞, 1}]] //
    Normal) // FullSimplify[#, m > 0] &
(* (4^-m (1 - a)^(-1 + 2 (-1 + a) m) a^(-1 - 2 a m))/(Sqrt[m] π^(3/2)) *)
Exp[(Series[Log[%], {a, 1/2, 2}] // Normal) /. a -> k/m]
(* (4 E^((-(1/2) + k/m)^2 (4 - 4 m)))/(Sqrt[m] π^(3/2)) *)
Limit[Integrate[%, {k, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> m > 1], m -> ∞]
(* 2/π *)
```

which provides a superior derivation, one not involving curve-fitting.

Comment: Thank you. If there is no update in a few days I will accept your answer. I would love to see your improved answer of course!

Comment: @felipa  Thanks for the reminder.  The improved derivation has been added.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[expr]

expr[n_Integer] := 
  n*Sum[Binomial[2 n - 4 i, n - 2 i]*Binomial[n, 2 i]*
      Binomial[4 i, 2 i], {i, 0, Floor[n/2]}]/2^(3 n - 1);

expr2 = expr[10000] // N
```

> 0.63662

```
RootApproximant[expr2*Pi]/Pi
```

> 2/Pi